# i3wm opacity with Compton

Tags: opacity, i3

Everything in my Compton config works fine except for the `opacity-rule`

```
active-opacity = 0.75;
inactive-opacity = 0.75;

opacity-rule = ["90:class_g = 'google-chrome'"];
```

I am using Compton from the Arch repos.
I can't find much documentation, I am just wondering if the newest version works differently than it used to? (I remember this working at one time)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

Possibly this is problem -

> Let’s face it: Using transparency (or ARGB background with transparent parts) on any window decorated by i3 is known to break.
>
> The problem is in how i3 adds title bars to windows. Unlike most window managers, i3 creates a completely separate window for the title bar (rather than wrapping it inside a frame window that contains both the application window and its title bar). So the first problem comes up: When using -i (inactive-opacity), the window and its title bar are not associated, and we frequently can’t give the title bar the correct opacity.

(from https://github.com/chjj/compton/wiki/faq#3-why-does-transparency-not-work-correctly-in-i3).